# setOnClickListener to only one view of relative layout which contains many other views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout consisting of few custom views, When I click on one of the views say "NavigationSelector" the other view say "AssistanceSelector" must be modified. I have added setOnClickListener event for object of NavigationSelector but I have observed that anywhere I click on entire relative layout the NavigationClickListener is called.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <com.dashboard.customviews.NavigationSelector
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigationSelector">
    </com.dashboard.customviews.NavigationSelector>

    <com.dashboard.customviews.AssistanceSelector
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/assistanceSelector">
    </com.dashboard.customviews.AssistanceSelector> 

Activity.java:

   NavigationSelector objNavigationSelector=null;
   objNavigationSelector=(NavigationSelector)findViewById(R.id.navigationSelector);
   objNavigationSelector.setOnClickListener(new NavigationClickListener(this));

class NavigationClickListener implements OnClickListener

public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.navigationSelector: //do required stuff 
             break;
        ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag `android:clickable="false"` to the layout items you don't want to be clicked.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm afraid it does not work. I set the android:clickable="false" to all other items in the relative layout but still the click is getting recongnized.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your two views share the same position. Fix your layout params, both have `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Comment: No in the custom view I have placed one object above the other

Comment: NavigationSelector cutomview:
int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
int centreX = 10;       
int NaviSelectorHeight = NaviSelector.getHeight();
int NaviSelectorcentreY = (canvasHeight - NaviSelectorHeight)/2-40;
canvas.drawBitmap(NaviSelector, centreX, NaviSelectorcentreY, SelectorPaint);

AssistanceSelector cutomview:

int centreX = 10;        
int AssistSelectorHeight = AssistSelector.getHeight();
int AssistSelectorcentreY = (canvasHeight - AssistSelectorHeight)/2;
canvas.drawBitmap(AssistSelector, centreX, AssistSelectorcentreY, SelectorPaint);